# create my own permission in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to know how I can add a new permission in drupal, for example, in drupal when I'm editing the roles permission I select the permission  `administer filters` to grant it, so I need a new permission like `Allow preauthorized tickets` for my own aplication, how I can add it to the list, to be granted to any rol.

Any advice will be usefull to me.

Comment: Even if closed, this should be moved to the Drupal subsite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [`hook_perm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_perm/6) in a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_perm() {
  return array('allow preauthorized tickets');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just as a reference in Drupal 7 this has changed to [`hook_permission()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7):

```
function hook_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer my module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer my module'), 
      'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here you can find an [implementation example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/page_example!page_example.module/group/page_example/7).